# Style - Setting onclick in HTML or in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a question about style and best practices.

If you have an html page with a lot of buttons connected to functions, would you rather set the onclick functions inside the input tag of the button, or would it be better to create a handler controller in Javascript that attaches onclick handlers to each button?

*I forgot to mention that the onclicks would be attached to a call to an existing function.  I'm not actually trying to cram in anonymous functions in the HTML!

I'm thinking that doing it all in Javascript would separate javascript from html, keeping my html page 'purer'.  In addition, if the buttons are spread out among the page, a controller will have all their handlers in one location.

But I'm also wondering if I would be create a lot of unnecessary code.  I also think setting the onclick in my html page would be more readable to other coders, since they wouldn't have to look for which functions the buttons are tied to.

Which do you think is preferable?

Comment: Well there is apparently a consensus about avoiding inline JS.  Thanks for the answers!  I'm glad I asked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keeping JS out of your tags is best practice. HTML is for content. CSS is for appearance. JS is for behavior. Keeping them all separate makes for a more semantically organized document.

Once you are accustomed to it, seeing the event handlers defined in a script is not too difficult to understand.

Answer (score 1):

Separating CSS, JS from the HTML considered a better practice.

You can still leave the onclick functions and just creating them on the seperate JS file.

Answer (score 0):

Putting onclick handlers inside html has higher risk for memory leaks.